# Output of Matlab FFT function different from Apple swift FFT function vDSP_fft_zripD() for the same audio samples

Tags: swift, matlab, audio, fft, accelerate-framework

I have been trying to convert a routine developed in Matlab which involves generation of spectrogram of a given input audio(.wav) sample. It seems like the output vector generated by Matlab N-Point FFT() function is totally different from what the output Apple Swift vDSP_fft_zripD()/DFT function generates.
I have used the same length = 256 for both FFT functions.
Please help me understand what has gone wrong.

Code used for DFT computation:

```
var xim = Matrix(rows: Int(ncol), columns: Int(nwind))
var xo = Matrix(rows: Int(256), columns: Int(ncol))
var xom = Matrix(rows: Int(256), columns: Int(ncol))
//ComputeDFT
var setup = vDSP_DFT_zop_CreateSetupD(nil, vDSP_Length(256),     vDSP_DFT_Direction.FORWARD)
vDSP_DFT_ExecuteD(setup!, xin.grid, xim.grid, &xo.grid, &xom.grid)
vDSP_DFT_DestroySetupD(setup)
```

Code used for FFT computation:

```
var complex = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: &xin.grid, imagp: &xim.grid)
let setup = vDSP_create_fftsetupD(vDSP_Length(8), FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2))
vDSP_fft_zipD(setup!, &complex, 1, vDSP_Length(8), FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))
vDSP_destroy_fftsetupD(setup)
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

The input Vector with audio samples is a 200*367 matrix. Matrix is a sample struct for representing a Matrix as described in Swift programming guide.

**Edit:**
Adding the input and output from both tools/languages. As the vectors are very large, I have added few elements only starting from index zero.

**Input vector :**
[-0.00271,0.0030692,-0.0021352,0.00024746,0.0020133,-0.0037754,0.0042984,-0.0039746,0.0029782,-0.0016908,0.00072967,0.00025264,-0.0017811,0.0030848,-0.003864,0.0038077,-0.0027115,0.0011812,3.6535e-05,-0.00096556,0.0015135,-0.0020024,0.0026543,-0.0035471,0.003833,-0.0029038,0.00080581,0.0016335,-0.0036754,0.0046871,-0.0046709,0.0038704,-0.0026682,0.0011636,0.0011325,-0.0031577,0.0047416,-0.004992,0.0044618,-0.0025552,1.6256e-05,0.002154,-0.0037306,0.0044153,-0.0041294,0.0029341,-0.00095727,-0.0015534,0.0034559,-0.00422,0.0038219,-0.0019568,-0.00053245,0.0028256,-0.0037762,0.0031305,-0.0018317,-6.0493e-05,0.0019649,-0.0031155,0.0030047,-0.0017529,-0.00033175,0.0018766,-0.0023804,0.0023192,-0.0016142,0.000167,0.0011867,-0.0021877,0.0025494,-0.001876,0.00016289,0.0016794,-0.0030841,0.0029513,-0.001546,-0.00041985,0.0020293,-0.0029071,0.0029482,-0.0020463,0.00034639,0.0015562,-0.002945,0.0031802,-0.0024713,0.00094019,0.0011893,-0.0027475,0.0031982,-0.0026046,0.0011999,0.0011738,-0.0028565,0.0028933,-0.0020686,0.00036563,0.0015152,-0.0020058,0.0012147,-9.547e-05,-0.00086167,0.0012652,-0.00024497,-0.00070934,0.00080213,-0.0007644,0.00034717,0.00019124,-0.00068835,0.001065,-0.00089429,-0.00010974,0.00058773,-0.000252,2.9415e-05,0.00058989,-0.00064257,0.00026438,0.00069545,-0.0015118,0.0021125,-0.0015504,0.00012918,0.0013358,-0.0020866,0.0018168,-0.00091418,-0.00068213,0.0012723,-0.00089738,-0.00015865,0.0012453,-0.0018815,0.0012146,-7.5193e-05,-0.0012242,0.0026592,-0.0028895,0.0023152,-0.00070381,-0.00054546,0.0020269,-0.0026833,0.0029293,-0.0029335,0.0023192,-0.0013521,-0.00048626,0.0023996,-0.0041625,0.0048257,-0.0042148,0.0022997,0.00022326,-0.0024101,0.0037688,-0.0039516,0.0033247,-0.0023775,0.0014604,-0.00036782,-0.0012808,0.0027987,-0.0037946,0.0041517,-0.0037643,0.0023942,-0.0006965,-0.0015658,0.003311,-0.0041734,0.0040849,-0.0033599,0.0018954,-0.00064371,-0.00068474,0.0017433,-0.0027362,0.0033796,-0.0039995,0.0037609,-0.0025085,0.0010393,0.0010271,-0.0032064,0.0050583,-0.0055993,0.004724,-0.0027108,0.00054102,0.0021301,-0.0043609,0.0053663,-0.0049718,0.0036362,-0.0019156,-4.1777e-05,0.0016869,-0.0035035,0.0045614,-0.0046339,0.0038164,-0.0021175,-0.00032272,0.0027516,-0.0045019,0.0046773,-0.0036788,0.0017863,-1.9075e-05,-0.0017555,0.0028148,-0.0028403,0.0023974,-0.0011883,0.0001456,0.0006734,-0.0011072,0.0014189,-0.0015557,0.0014089,-0.0010891,-7.4845e-05,0.0011193,-0.001616,0.0012094,-0.00023958,-0.00023938,0.00064001,-0.00042344,-0.00011397,0.00084473,-0.0011366,0.00092973,-3.0892e-05,-0.0012847,0.0020294,-0.0017584,0.0011103,-0.00027364,-0.00060126,0.0015109,-0.0016498,0.0016061,-0.00111,0.00027834,0.0004461,-0.00089267,0.0011691,-0.00049543,0.00010889,-0.00016164,0.00042353,-0.00084096,0.00082414,-0.00072703,0.00030549,0.00078561,-0.0021104,0.0027166,-0.0023947,0.0013189,0.00062278,-0.0022672,0.0029132,-0.0022861,0.00094974,0.00048735,-0.0015383,0.0013315,-0.00071071,0.00020489,4.0305e-06,5.5603e-05,-0.00029551,5.5331e-05,0.00081644,-0.0016154,0.0019444,-0.0010133,-0.00049176,0.0022637,-0.0035809,0.0032675,-0.0019021,-0.00038401,0.0027518,-0.0040653,0.0036291,-0.0016228,-0.001034,0.0029028,-0.0029811,0.0019119,-0.00018236,-0.0014305,0.0022457,-0.0018572,0.00075512,0.00075342,-0.0018176,0.0017062,-0.0010774,0.0003599,6.9605e-05,-0.00037473,0.00054361,-0.0012724,0.0020189,-0.0025683,0.0024655,-0.0016864,-0.00015796,0.0024744,-0.0042758,0.0049584,-0.0039011,0.001776,0.00104,-0.003405,0.0046894,-0.0049072,0.0038236,-0.0018416,-0.00055764,0.0021144,-0.0033064,0.0036506,-0.0030661,0.0023445,-0.0014618,0.00043919,0.00072334,-0.002128,0.0032335,-0.0040862,0.0041497,-0.0034212,0.0013225,0.0013626,-0.0035229,0.0046378,-0.0043603,0.0034822,-0.0019463,0.00050518,0.0011009,-0.0026392,0.0034365,-0.0037395,0.0030247,-0.0021802,0.00077206,0.00066201,-0.002011,0.0027188,-0.0028945,0.0030832,-0.0027156,0.001944,-0.00049603,-0.0014029,0.0031083,-0.0037175, ...]

**FFT Output from Matlab:**
[0.00010669,-6.2756e-05,-0.00022014,6.8741e-05,6.2219e-05,-4.383e-05,0.00028213,-0.00035134,8.9066e-05,1.5854e-05,3.3262e-05,-0.0002098,8.2673e-05,-0.00032642,0.0006539,0.00051418,-0.00046328,-0.00015942,-9.7775e-05,-0.00018529,-1.9093e-05,3.0632e-05,-0.00018141,0.00016401,0.00011009,-0.00022032,-0.00017468,0.00031629,-0.00041128,0.00058215,0.0010802,-0.00095458,-0.0010251,0.0015948,0.00043729,-0.00029125,-0.00067716,0.00056726,0.00072778,0.0001621,0.00042591,0.00011171,-0.0015602,-0.0010883,0.0007437,0.0002536,9.6448e-05,-0.00060308,0.00018436,0.0001537,-0.00020022,-0.0016456,-0.00023629,0.00097449,0.0011558,-7.7517e-05,-7.7646e-05,0.00095094,0.00037741,-0.001607,-0.00054529,0.00029874,0.00050468,-0.00035748,0.00012797,-0.00017766,0.00034368,-0.00039356,0.00052503,-0.00059456,0.00065017,-0.00077183,0.00072259,-0.00053729,0.00027889,-6.809e-06,-6.6142e-05,-0.00012311,-0.0007282,-0.00087728,-0.0012919,0.0017909,-0.002238,-0.00059899,0.0086773,0.0028204,-0.0042068,-0.0061266,0.00082671,0.0047689,-0.0016718,-0.0010595,-0.00017541,-0.00028367,0.0017714,0.0014909,-0.0024097,-0.0020627,0.00068466,0.0032626,0.001306,-0.006652,-0.0024463,0.006862,-3.6869e-05,-0.0053925,0.0051873,0.0015999,-0.0056532,0.0027179,0.0033196,0.00077156,0.00040536,0.00018704,-0.0024699,-0.004604,0.001993,0.00094948,-0.0013091,0.0021331,-0.0003634,-0.0046344,0.0012439,0.0038382,-0.00069769,-0.0016643,0.00063463,0.00067452,-0.00016044,0.00046627,-0.00068811,0.00032789,-7.8879e-05,4.2645e-05,-0.00028395,0.00021144,0.00013108,6.2968e-05,-0.00012994,6.292e-05,-7.2113e-05,4.6128e-06,-0.0010233,-0.0010764,0.00083336,-0.0068306,-0.0060089,0.015613,0.00053871,-0.0015825,0.0053616,-0.0050632,0.0010588,0.00057775,-0.0031409,-0.0035236,0.0035609,0.00013055,-0.00096763,0.0018079,0.0051199,0.0030635,-0.0033788,-0.0093476,-0.0070576,0.011838,0.010269,-0.0037519,0.0012323,-0.0087526,-0.0063813,0.0050926,0.0035392,9.0505e-05,-0.003189,0.0013741,0.0020016,-0.0010521,-0.0053241,-0.00046443,-6.5223e-05,0.0038023,0.0046873,-0.0017443,-0.0020335,-7.5489e-05,6.9384e-07,0.00035444,0.00025019,-0.00056916,0.0002095,5.9823e-05,1.4288e-05,-7.5334e-05,-7.9357e-05,0.00018686,-0.00015902,0.00013156,7.5708e-05,-0.001042,-0.0010204,-0.010973,0.01179,0.019551,-0.0017324,-0.015437,0.00022535,0.0034839,-0.0058964,0.0090677,-0.0069075,-0.0087819,0.0022964,0.0030456,0.0012804,0.0014501,0.00026958,0.0016503,0.0025635,-0.0015683,-0.0039377,-0.0081506,0.0081454,0.011452,0.00053368,-0.0038586,-0.01187,-0.0076128,0.0085288,0.006353,-0.0049609,0.00052668,0.0035362,0.00052944,0.00035163,0.0011963,2.8692e-05,-0.0018641,-0.0025637,-0.00054081,0.0003798,0.00028424,8.1081e-05,-0.00035377,-1.0134e-05,0.00015119,0.00019492,0.00025557,-4.6852e-05,-0.0002439,0.0002505,-3.2231e-05,-0.0002206,0.00016161,0.00081969,-0.0028257,-0.012475,0.002915,0.0042904,0.0039851,0.0025485,-0.0083873,0.0043524,0.0043513,-0.0042197,0.0043643,0.0036944,-0.0060465,0.0033417,-0.0014454,-0.00020823,0.0043207,-0.0021817,-0.0051255,-0.00092433,0.011741,0.0061367,-0.013602,-0.0012163,0.00713,-0.0095453,-0.0086194,0.011051,0.0050328,-0.0014045,0.0033446,-0.0031947,0.0012951,-0.0020455,-0.0064324,0.0024793,0.0047256,-0.0007034,-0.0011523,-0.00056287,-0.00049678,0.00022316,0.00047549,0.00015309,-2.8236e-05,0.00034175,-0.00020625,-0.00027939,0.00018042,0.00018501,-0.00020505,0.00032836,-0.00012213,0.0028854,-0.0024295,-0.00092681,-0.0084069,-0.0091282,0.003407,-0.0011464,0.01675,0.0027304,-0.0054888,0.0051865,-0.0088288,0.0013642,0.0090739,-0.0025031,-0.001465,-0.0001324,-0.00095257,-0.0029116,-0.0040353,0.0013075,0.009332,0.0067453,-0.0074108,-0.0041978,-0.0040748,-0.0046779,0.0078169,0.0061305,-0.0069415,-0.0046845,0.0025245,0.0041822,-0.00031306,-0.0017069,0.0027801,0.00073892,-0.0016471,0.0002399,0.00064031,-2.6591e-05,-0.00028654,0.00051699,-0.00050492,8.2351e-05,0.00041114,-0.00019892,-0.00030789,-0.0001257,0.00037056,-6.8247e-05,0.00018746,-0.0002814,-0.00013427,7.2576e-06,0.00025716,-0.00014787,-7.8601e-05,0.00015129
-0.00028002+5.1865e-05i,-6.1965e-05+0.00046933i,0.00033604-8.0387e-05i,0.00018935-0.00031439i,-5.1941e-05-0.00028887i,2.0512e-05-0.00017434i,-0.00041901-7.1938e-05i,0.00029994+0.00038647i,0.00011229-0.0002497i,0.00011773-8.7151e-05i,-0.00019108-3.8344e-05i,0.00033091+0.00013141i,-0.00013792-0.00046781i,0.00010093+9.4704e-05i,0.00038644-8.8473e-05i,-0.00016489+0.00044999i,-0.00014516+9.0889e-05i,-0.00040125-2.0598e-05i,-9.411e-05+2.2678e-05i,-6.0504e-05-0.00018967i,0.00018448+3.8255e-05i,-0.00018873-0.00068665i,-0.00016111+0.0005025i,0.00071327-0.00037479i,-0.00025811-0.00036408i,-0.00030083-0.00011902i,0.00013252-9.077e-05i,0.00014738+1.5691e-05i,8.3591e-05-0.00048951i,2.7084e-05+0.00057306i,0.0005838+0.00055177i,-0.00097678-0.0003245i,-0.00015743+0.00018943i,0.00047775+0.00015785i,0.00021277+0.0011753i,-0.00055093-0.00023477i,-0.00073219+0.00050859i,0.00017225+0.00085093i,0.00055524+0.0010074i,-0.00027523+0.00055796i,-0.00089522+0.00049671i,-0.00094359+0.0024897i,-0.0001021-0.0015835i,-0.001775-3.5542e-05i,0.00079802+0.00058374i,-0.00024466-0.00076301i,-0.0014947+0.0012535i,0.0010008+0.00079092i,-0.00054116-0.0014888i,-0.0007496+0.0022971i,0.00096518-0.00087778i,-0.00055851-0.00067682i,-9.0887e-06-0.0021713i,0.0001151+0.00090246i,0.0020768+0.0012218i,4.7467e-05-0.0012672i,-0.0010921+0.00082123i,0.0010676+0.0014046i,-0.0006989+0.00027206i, ...]

**Output from iOS FFT function:**

***real***: [-0.05478454600000003, -0.02271826083895351, 0.02522335881426633, -0.004047944668648169, 0.03353372905082295, -0.01726943789637264, -0.03929163098048931, 0.08002083358826738, -0.0006665247965166616, -0.01647581738761391, 0.0372807309076925, -0.04470671290333615, 0.009179288123689823, 0.006589678598556904, -0.01732711264605497, -0.08286873126564648, -0.01217434532674255, 0.04884142060883784, -0.002975028492892426, 0.07264927268510701, -0.03082418329212244, 0.01026404557415052, 0.005905716782577217, 0.0598614644911639, -0.0002154346501241841, -0.08134118150927641, -0.02791732594087061, -0.08089620676644146, 0.09363464811649133, 0.005938318937817577, -0.006420205200110846, 0.08347864778328129, -0.05414207960850229, 0.01222740837930163, -0.01290185689111754, -0.07378697918728867, -0.04526959973697092, 0.1243407711017572, 0.04216833211421128, 0.00684172341497322, 0.007880533933445986, -0.1198006042186608, 0.02661921153178444, -0.04000947694785679, -0.001203061017021804, 0.02997462499821713, -0.003752776120691165, ...]

***imaginary***: [0, 0.008652893272646775, -0.05076918420077416, 0.02904127183295504, -0.02454442663055361, -0.001761122653129804, -0.04238914692925354, -0.00640014629546775, 0.06031142821007651, 0.01453818184978239, 0.02656969287570559, -0.04011221475625854, 0.00195000220345749, 0.0004864831837713551, 0.07464910868122639, -0.01285093612695411, -0.06668673883119097, -0.05326076214519457, -0.01943845848038781, 0.06103132496204326, -0.03375528557099017, 0.033938967809654, -0.01560006591308127, -0.01101511425661522, 0.115847692434482, -0.009639236152547076, -0.007221175322939734, -0.05343150402880979, -0.0443090179587378, 0.0159234353665165, -0.06639207975402919, 0.05394626193285895, 0.04208497771047572, 0.006982966976459237, 0.06214303901180915, -0.03166928903492799, -0.08822481698781517, -0.04929210096564096, 0.05388439271666732, 0.0468956055563163, 0.05706426445833224, 0.02317321558944471, -0.08072619702650299, 0.04598595727510245, -0.08649331584683564, 0.009320047710367957, -0.005092909460828264, -0.07262233366799267, ...]

Comment: Please provide the FFT of e.g. a vector like `[1,0,0,0]` and `[1,1,0,0]` in both languages. Also some plots would be nice.

Comment: These functions, incidentally, are not 'swift' functions - they are C functions provided in the Accelerate Framework which you are calling from Swift.

Comment: @flawr, added a input and output vectors to the main question :)

Comment: @acn Both these do not seem to be complete. Please provide the FFTs of some *simple* examples as stated above. This is for judging what might be done differently with those different methods.

Comment: @flawr, sorry for the late reply. I haven't had much time then to work on fixing this, so I used Armadillo C++ library: http://arma.sourceforge.net as it was sufficient for the task I was trying to accomplish. Thanks for your help.